# Is there a way to manually validate object typing?

Tags: python, python-typing

I was writing a test case for a function that accepts `typing.BinaryIO` that comes from `fastapi.UploadFile.file`.

```
def upload_binary(data: typing.BinaryIO):
    ...
```

I was confused what kind of object do I create that will pass type check. I tried `io.StringIO` and `io.BytesIO`, and the only way to check which one will be accepted as `typing.BinaryIO` was to use IDE's highlighting. It didn't accept `StringIO` but accepted `BytesIO`.

So my question - is there a way in Python to manually check if object will be validated with given typing hint.

For example some function like

```
file1 = StringIO("text")
file2 = BytesIO(b"text")
typing_check(file1, typing.BinaryIO)  # >>> False
typing_check(file2, typing.BinaryIO)  # >>> True
```

UPD
Looking at `starlette/datastructures.py` we have

```
class UploadFile:
    ...
    file: typing.BinaryIO

    def __init__(...):
        if self.file is None:
            self.file = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile(...)
```

And if you try to test it

```
s = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
isinstance(s, typing.BinaryIO)  # >>> False
```

Comment: Do `isinstance` or `type(file1) == ...` work in this case?

Comment: @Kraigolas no, it doesn't. At least I didn't find a way to ever get `True`. Even `isinstance(file2, typing.BinaryIO)` returns `False`. Which is pretty  reasonable since it's an object of another class.

Comment: It's an interesting question and off the top of my head I'd say "no", because static type checking is not actually built into Python, even though it's added many facilities to support it. However, as suggested by @Kraigolas you could try `isinstance()` as many types are also Abstract Base Classes (direct type comparison won't work for this, however)

Comment: @Iguananaut yeah, I was wondering exactly about "these" types. But since IDE somehow realises it - it's probably possible. Maybe with some external tools.

Comment: Though it turns out that isn't the case for `typing.IO`. Strange. Maybe it should be.

Comment: IDEs are using their own external static type checkers, such as Pydantic

Comment: Ide does not try to run your code. It performs static analysis. If you want to perform static type checking, you can use [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which has convenient CLI instead (other options include [pyre](https://pyre-check.org/), [pytype](https://github.com/google/pytype) and [pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright)). Annotations are **not** (and hopefully will never be, as stated in PEP484) enforced by python interpreter.

Comment: [In general, types should not be used with `isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). There is no *general* recipe on in-python type validation. For some cases (`Sequence` or `runtime_checkable` `Protocol`) you can use `isinstance`, but it can fail in other cases. I'd suggest to use external type checker (or `mypy` [playground](https://mypy-play.net/) to learn typing and understand what will be compatible and what - not.

Comment: @SUTerliakov maybe I expressed myself incorrect. I wasn't trying to find a way to do this in pure Python. Any technology is okay for this. Such as mypy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you can try building basic static type checking decorator using annotations and `inspect` module.

`inspect.signature(fn)` can read annotations of function parameters, and you can compare types with `isinstance` function.

```
import inspect

def static_type_checker(fn):
    spec = inspect.signature(fn)
    params = spec.parameters
    def inner_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        for arg, (name, param) in zip(args, params.items()):
            assert isinstance(arg, param.annotation)
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            assert isinstance(value, params[key].annotation)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner_fn

@static_type_checker
def sample(a: int):
    print(a)

sample(1) # prints 1
sample("a") # AssertionError
```

Note that this is not perfect solution. It has many limitations, like when giving various-length arguments. I'm just suggesting basic idea.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and reply a bit later.